# How to sort RTP packets for downloading Music file in python

Tags: python

I am receiving a music file from a server, but I am not able to sort the packets. That's why I have a distortion and incomplete MP3 file. How can I sort it ?

```
with open('Music.mp3', 'wb') as f:
  print 'file opened'
  for g in range(5000):

    data = s.recv(1000)
    sequence1= data[2]
    sequence2 = data[3]

    a = ord(sequence1)
    b = ord(sequence2)
    #print 'Sequence', a , b

    payload = {b: data[12:]}
    sorted(payload)
    print payload
    #SeqNum = (MSB << 8) + LSB
    print('receiving data...')
    #print "DATA IN FILE : ", payload
    f.write(payload[b])
    if payload is None:
        f.close()
        break

print('Successfully get the file')
```

Comment: No [mcve]. What's `s`? How is data delivered/formatted?

Comment: WTH, are you trying to get RAW data from RTP, put it into ".mp3" and expect it to be playable?! These are completely different formats, RTFM on them. You'll need to decode & recode the data & metadata - it's so much work you're gonna have to use existing libraries that can work with the formats.

Comment: I am getting the data and also able to play it using a media player. The problem is I have glitches in the received audio file because the packets are not in the order